# how to let the user answer same question if input is invalid in a quiz

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm making a quiz-game for my school project. I'm having trouble to let the user answer the same question if the input is invalid. I want to let the user answer the same question when no valid input on all questions.

here's my code so far :

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
    
        String quest1 = ("Who founded the company spaceX?\na: Will Smith\nb: Elon Musk\nc: Kevin Hart");
        String quest2 = ("Which sport is the most famous in the world?\na: Football\nb: Basketball\nc: Tennis");
        
        questionsAndAnswers [] questionAnswers = {          
                new questionsAndAnswers(quest1, "b"),
                new questionsAndAnswers(quest2, "a")
        };
    
        doQuiz(questionAnswers);
    }

    public static void doQuiz(questionsAndAnswers[] questionAnswers) {
        
        int points = 0;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean looper = true;
        
        while (looper) {
            
            for(int i = 0; i < questionAnswers.length; i++){
                System.out.println(questionAnswers[i].questions);
            
                String userAnswer = input.nextLine();
    
                if(!"a".equals(userAnswer) && !"b".equals(userAnswer) && !"c".equals(userAnswer)) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
                    break;
                }
                
                else if(userAnswer.equals(questionAnswers[i].answers)) {            
                    points++;
                    System.out.println("Correct! Your points:" + points);
                }
                continue;
            }
            looper = false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop INSTEAD of a `for` loop:

```
        int i = 0;
        while (i < questionAnswers.length){
            System.out.println(questionAnswers[i].questions);
        
            String userAnswer = input.nextLine();

            if(userAnswer.equals(questionAnswers[i].answers)) {            
                points++;
                System.out.println("Correct! Your points:" + points);
                ++i;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
                // do not increment i
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the code is great so far.
When a user answers a question with an invalid answer you already detect that which is great however what you want to do is re ask the user for input
so if you keep track of if a user has entered a valid or not

```
boolean hasEnteredValidAnswer = false
while(!hasEnteredValidAnswer) {
    String userAnswer = input.nextLine();

    if("a".equals(userAnswer) || "b".equals(userAnswer) || "c".equals(userAnswer)) {
        hasEnteredValidAnswer = true                    
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: @jsheeran thanks it should be or not and missed it in editing the code to test for the positive case instead of the negative case